# 14.10 in Ubuntu touch is EOL or not?

Tags: discussion

Recently I observed a [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692868/ubuntu-update-installation-failing-on-my-bq-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition) with 14.10 in Ubuntu touch ( **BQ Aquaris E4.5** ) The Ubuntu version released in **11 February 2015** (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQ_Aquaris_E4.5)).

Also in Ubuntu touch [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices), The last supported date mentioned *unknown*.

My question:

Is Ubuntu touch with 14.10 is EOL or not ?

Because we generally close Q with 14.10, I too did same in this case, but after receiving a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692868/ubuntu-update-installation-failing-on-my-bq-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition?noredirect=1#comment1012674_692868), I decided to get clear clarity.

**EDIT**:

To extend my question to make it generalized,

If the question is *not about upgrading* but related to **14.10 Ubuntu touch** (or any Ubuntu touch with EOL version) is off-topic?

Comment: Ubuntu Touch is kind of uncharted territory. For now I say we  point all people running EoL releases to upgrade. If they need help upgrading then we help them. We could probably use a few canonical questions for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my (not so) humble opinion, 14.10 is an EOL release, so questions about *14.10 itself* are off-topic, but **questions on how to upgrade are not**.

In this particular case, I don't think BQ will unpack all phones in of their warehouse and upgrade them to 15.10 before shipping, so in my *humble* opinion, we should reopen this question and then protect it...

That way, we can let this be the "one" exception: all other questions related to upgrading can then be closed onto this one! (thanks [@Rinzwind](https://askubuntu.com/users/15811/rinzwind) for the tip!)

## :-)

Comment: I accept it  for  this _particular_ question,Will you please make it generalised ? =) @Fabby